# Pandas divide returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to divide two columns but they return NaN.
**Output of column1**

```
print(ireland_population['population'])
104    5023108
Name: population, dtype: int64
```

**Output of column2**

```
print(ireland['people_fully_vaccinated'])
124391    4061525.0
Name: people_fully_vaccinated, dtype: float64
```

**Output of division**

```
ans = ireland['people_fully_vaccinated'] /  ireland_population['population']

print(ans)
104      NaN
124391   NaN
dtype: float64
```

I just want the one number for the percentage of people who were fully vaccinated in Ireland.
I have also tried converting ireland_population to a float like below but that didn't help.
`ireland_population['population'] = ireland_population['population'].astype('float64')`

Comment: I notice the outputs for your print statements have two numbers, are you sure you're dividing a number by a number and not an array by an array or something? otherwise I'm not sure what the 104 and 124391 are

Comment: I think they are the row numbers of the real values i.e. 104(row number) 5023108 (Ireland's population). I have tried dividing people_fully_vaccinated by 3 and that worked. It just isn't working when I divide by this other column

Comment: See if type(ireland_population['population']) is an int64 as expected. I suspect it's not and pandas is giving you some result object rather than a plain number, so then you'd need to extract it. Could be wrong though, I'm not really a python or pandas dev :p

Comment: I used `print(ireland_population['population'].dtypes)` and it returned int64 so it is int64

Comment: You probably should use: `ireland['people_fully_vaccinated'].squeeze() /  ireland_population['population'].squeeze()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your code above retrieves the indices with the values.
Try to use the next code:

```
ans = ireland['people_fully_vaccinated'].values / ireland_population['population'].values
```